# How to print row x without knowing the index in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe with 45 columns and 11k rows. This dataframe consist of players. Columns displaying their name, player_id, rating, height etc. Pretend you have the name of a player in the dataframe, or their ID, and you want to access the entire row of that player. You want to see all the information of that individual, but you only have one unique identifyer.

I tried using `df.loc[[id_number]]`, but that only takes me to the index of the dataframe, which does not correspond to player_id.

Hopefully I explained it well enough. If you have any questions, please post them below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try applying a mask:

```py
df[df.playerId == id_number]
```

Assuming `playerId` is the name of the column containing the player ids.

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked perfectly. This taught me that mask's work other ways as well. Managed to create a new dataframe consisting only of players with a rating higher than '66'. I would upvote you, but apparently I cannot do that with only 11 points on my profile.

Comment: @Kenso33 Yeah mask generalize to inequalities or functions, they also can be composed with boolean operators. Plenty of uses to that, they are the bread and butter of data filtering.

Answer (score 5):

```
df.loc[df['column_name'] == some_value]
```

Related to https://stackoverflow.com/a/17071908/17487637

Comment: This works as well as the first answer, thank you. I cannot upvote you because I apparently need 15 points on my profile first.

Comment: Good! I’m glad I helped you.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I have understood, you want to query a dataframe based on one unique identifier. Let's suppose you only have **player name**.

```
df[df.player_name==playername]
```

Here playername is the variable where you will store your desired player name.

Comment: Thank you. This will accomplish my goal.

Comment: Great @Kenso33. Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

I use this in my code to find what i need in excel file. Mayby will be helpful for you.

```
 search = input('\t\t    Find row:  ')
 xlsxfile = pd.read_excel('your_filename.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
df = xlsxfile[xlsxfile['name_of_your_column' ].str.contains(search , na=False)]

dx = (df[['name', 'player_id','height']])
print(dx)
```

You will need some third party module for this like openpyxl.

Comment: The first answer was what I was looking for, but thank you for taking your time trying to help.

Comment: No problem , first answer looks more clearly anyway. Good luck